# Evaluate a function on .SDcols and return all columns in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table "result" which is the output of eclat() from arules package in R.

```
        lhs           rhs         sup        conf      lift       itemset
1: {XXXXXXXXXXX} {XXXXXXXXOOO} 0.001635323 1.0000000 611.50000       1
2: {XXXXXXXXOOO} {XXXXXXXXXXX} 0.001635323 1.0000000 611.50000       1
3: {XXXXX00XXXX} {XXXXXX0XXXX} 0.001635323 1.0000000  32.18421       2
4: {XXXXXXX00XX} {XXX0XXXXXXX} 0.001635323 0.5000000 203.83333       3
5: {XXX0XXXXXXX} {XXXXXXX00XX} 0.001635323 0.6666667 203.83333       3
```

I want to replace the "{" and "}" in lhs and rhs column of "result". I am able to run gsub and return back a data.table with lhs and rhs values only using the following statement:

```
result[,lapply(.SD,gsub,pattern = "{",replacement = "",fixed = T),.SDcols=c("lhs","rhs")][,lapply(.SD,gsub,pattern="}",replacement="",fixed=T)]
```

Output that I am getting:

```
         lhs           rhs      
1:  XXXXXXXXXXX   XXXXXXXXOOO
2:  XXXXXXXXOOO   XXXXXXXXXXX
3:  XXXXX00XXXX   XXXXXX0XXXX
4:  XXXXXXX00XX   XXX0XXXXXXX
5:  XXX0XXXXXXX   XXXXXXX00XX
```

But I also want to retain the values of sup, conf, lift and itemset.

Expected output:

```
        lhs           rhs         sup      conf      lift         itemset
1:  XXXXXXXXXXX   XXXXXXXXOOO  0.001635323 1.0000000 611.50000       1
2:  XXXXXXXXOOO   XXXXXXXXXXX  0.001635323 1.0000000 611.50000       1
3:  XXXXX00XXXX   XXXXXX0XXXX  0.001635323 1.0000000  32.18421       2
4:  XXXXXXX00XX   XXX0XXXXXXX  0.001635323 0.5000000 203.83333       3
5:  XXX0XXXXXXX   XXXXXXX00XX  0.001635323 0.6666667 203.83333       3
```

How to get the remaining columns with their names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do the assignment to replace in place the output we got from the `lapply`

```
result[,c("lhs", "rhs") := lapply(.SD,gsub,pattern = "[{}]",
       replacement = ""), .SDcols=c("lhs","rhs")]
result
#           lhs         rhs         sup      conf      lift itemset
#1: XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXOOO 0.001635323 1.0000000 611.50000       1
#2: XXXXXXXXOOO XXXXXXXXXXX 0.001635323 1.0000000 611.50000       1
#3: XXXXX00XXXX XXXXXX0XXXX 0.001635323 1.0000000  32.18421       2
#4: XXXXXXX00XX XXX0XXXXXXX 0.001635323 0.5000000 203.83333       3
#5: XXX0XXXXXXX XXXXXXX00XX 0.001635323 0.6666667 203.83333       3
```

Comment: I was tried this way too:    result[,.(c(lapply(.SD,gsub,pattern = "{",replacement = "",fixed = T),sup,conf,lift,itemset)),.SDcols=c("lhs","rhs")][,.(c(lapply(.SD,gsub,pattern="}",replacement="",fixed=T),sup,conf,lift,itemset)),.SDcols=c("lhs","rhs")]   It says...as long as it returns a list, we get the data.table with the columns. Any idea why this did not work?

Comment: @Tushar Without the assignment or `set` the values are not updated in the columns in original dataset

Answer (score 1):

```
library('data.table')
for(col in c("lhs", "rhs")){
  set(result, , col, gsub( "[{}]", '', result[[col]] ) )  # using set() function is faster than `[`. see ?`:=`
}

result
#            lhs         rhs         sup      conf      lift itemset
# 1: XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXOOO 0.001635323 1.0000000 611.50000       1
# 2: XXXXXXXXOOO XXXXXXXXXXX 0.001635323 1.0000000 611.50000       1
# 3: XXXXX00XXXX XXXXXX0XXXX 0.001635323 1.0000000  32.18421       2
# 4: XXXXXXX00XX XXX0XXXXXXX 0.001635323 0.5000000 203.83333       3
# 5: XXX0XXXXXXX XXXXXXX00XX 0.001635323 0.6666667 203.83333       3
```